# How to view over thousands of files in a directory through the command line?

Tags: go

I have downloaded over 500 Gb  of data to a single directory off of AWS.
Whenever I try to access that directory, the command line hangs and doesn't show me anything.

I'm trying to run some code that will interact with the files by printing out the path of each file but the command line hangs and then exits the program.

The program definitely starts execution because "Printing file path's" gets displayed to the console.

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Printing file path's")

    err := filepath.Walk(source,
        func(fpath string, info os.FileInfo, err error) {
            if !info.IsDir() && file path.Ext(fpath)==".txt" {
                fmt.Println(fpath)
            }
         }
    }
}
```

How should I handle the situation of being able to view all the files in the command line and why is this program not working?

UPDATE:
By using

```
files, err := dir.Readdir(10)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
```

I was able to snap up the first 10 folders/files in the directory.
Using a loop I could keep doing this until I hit the end of the directory.

This doesn't rely on ordering the files/folders as does the walk function and so its more efficient.

Comment: Maybe you can move the files into multiple separate directories.

Comment: Is there a command I could use that would do that?

Comment: The amount of data is likely irrelevant, the number of files is relevant. How many files? How many directories?

Comment: I don't know the exact number.  It's > 500 GB of data.  Each directory has only a few text files at most so its a lot of files and directories.

Comment: handle that err and see what happended

Comment: Walk slurps up the file info for the entire directory and sorts by name before invoking the walk function for items in the directory.  This can produce a noticeable lag on huge directories and slow file systems. If this is the problem, then you can see results sooner by opening the directory with os.Open and iterating through the files using [os.Readdir](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Readdir) or [os.Readdirnames](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Readdirnames).  Use a small positive number for `n` when calling one of the read functions.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I'd argue that in this case, `Walk` actually breaks the principle of least surprise, since last time I checked, I walk step by step. Thank you for the info, though.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg the "steps" being "walked" are the files/directories, not the steps in the process of reading/sorting/listing them, so your surprise is just misunderstanding. The reason it sorts is to make the order of items walked deterministic; non-deterministic ordering would likely be much more surprising to a typical developer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The possible performance issue with filepath.Walk [is clearly documented](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Walk):

> The files are walked in lexical order, which makes the output deterministic but means that for very large directories Walk can be inefficient.

Use [os.File.Readdir](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Readdir) to iterate files in filesystem order:

> Readdir reads the contents of the directory associated with file and returns a slice of up to n FileInfo values, as would be returned by Lstat, in directory order. Subsequent calls on the same file will yield further FileInfos.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    dir, err := os.Open("/tmp")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for {
        files, err := dir.Readdir(10)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        for _, fi := range files {
            classifier := ""
            if fi.IsDir() {
                classifier = "/"
            }
            fmt.Printf("%v %12d %s%s\n",
                fi.ModTime().UTC().Truncate(time.Second),
                fi.Size(),
                fi.Name(), classifier,
            )
        }
    }
}
```